# Change array key and group key with the same value

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [variant_name] => Green
        [product_id] => 2
        [variant_id] => 67
        [amount] => 1000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [variant_name] => Red
        [product_id] => 2
        [variant_id] => 68
        [amount] => 0
    )
)
```

This expected to be like this:

```
Array (
[2] => array (
       [67] => array (
                  [variant_id] => Green
                  [amount] => 1000
                 (   
       [68] => array (
                  [variant_id] => Red
                  [amount] => 0
                 ( 


)
```

Which is group by product_id and then split into arrays group by variant_id.
How can I do that. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Write a loop. It check check whether the result array already has an element with the product_id as key. If not, it creates it, with its value being an array. Then it adds the current element to the sub-array, with the variant_id as the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($values as $product)
{
$newValues[$product["product_id"]][$product["variant_id"]]=
 array(
  'product_name'=>$product["variant_name"],
  'amount'=>$product["amount"]
  );
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [67] => Array
                (
                    [product_name] => Green
                    [amount] => 1000
                )

            [68] => Array
                (
                    [product_name] => Red
                    [amount] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

**Note** You have `variant_name` in your original array and you are using that as `variant_id` in your output. You can play with indexes in this code. I just used what seemed to match.

Answer (score 1):

A simple foreach loop should suffice. Of course, you need to build them inside a new array. Consider this example: (In your expected example, I think you were referring to `variant_name`)

```
 $values = array( array( 'variant_name' => 'Green', 'product_id' => 2, 'variant_id' => 67, 'amount' => 1000, ), array( 'variant_name' => 'Red', 'product_id' => 2, 'variant_id' => 68, 'amount' => 0, ), );

$new_values = array();
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    $new_values[$value['product_id']][$value['variant_id']] = array(
        'variant_name' => $value['variant_name'],
        'amount' => $value['amount'],
    );
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_values);
echo '</pre>';
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aZxvhV)

Comment: Where's the product_id in your result?